# Checking if values of a row are consecutive

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6
0    5  10  12  35  70  80
1   10  11  23  40  42  47
2    5  26  27  38  60  65
```

Where all the values in each row are different and have an increasing order.

I would like to create a new column with `1` or `0` if there are at least 2 consecutive numbers.
For example the second and third row have `10` and `11`, and `26` and `27`. Is there a more pythonic way than using an iterator?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) for difference per rows, compare by `1`, check if at least one `True` per rows and last cast to integers:

```
df['check'] = df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
    1   2   3   4   5   6  check
0   5  10  12  35  70  80      0
1  10  11  23  40  42  47      1
2   5  26  27  38  60  65      1
```

For improve performance use `numpy`:

```
arr = df.values
df['check'] = np.any(((arr[:, 1:] - arr[:, :-1]) == 1), axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: `df.eq(df.shift(axis=1)+1).any(1).astype(int)
`